# Capture an image with webcam and find the distance between the lines

Tags: c#

I am trying to create an application with C# WPF that uses a camera to take a photo of a piece of plastic.

On this piece of plastic, there is a place in the middle that is covered in a chemical substance.

I would like to measure the distance from the edge of the paper to the edge of the covered part on both sides.

I have been googling for ages but I can't find anything similar to what I want to do.

Here is a picture of what I mean:

[image: Picture of what I mean]

I just want a push in the right direction so I know where to start!

Comment: Maybe you could briefly tell us more about your Google searches?
I'm not into picture analysis, but two things I am thinking of:
- I think a scale is needed to be able to measure things from a picture (or you will get relative measures)
- It is not specific to C# or WPF, it is picture analysis related

Comment: I think relative measures will be just fine. 

Tried googling for c# camera capture detection lines. But didn't give me anything remotely close to what I am searching for.

Comment: I guess you should look for "shape recognition" libraries, the term "detection lines" you are using is confusing IMO.

Comment: Yeah, true. Found alot more useful information on google now! Cheers :D

Comment: Once you have a clean solution to your problem, please come back here a post an answer to your question (or edit your question). That's how the SO community is working and improving ;-)

Comment: Is the page 8 1/2 by 11 "? because if so, that's a starting point.